# What does this result from printf indicate?

Tags: c, printf

I periodically get extraneous results when I run a program I have constructed. Instead of printing a float, I get this: `-1.#IO`. What does this result indicate? A divide by zero?

In my experience, if the result was an overflow then it should still print correctly, just a an incorrect value (perhaps some large negative).

Here is what I am getting *most* of the time:

[image]

Here is what happens about every 6-7 runs.

[image]

If I run the program using a constant seed (assuming that seed produces correct results), then everything works fine indefinitely. However, if I run using a random seed, like time(0), I tend to see this program explode at run-time.

In short, has anyone experienced this result before? Just looking for a starting point to dive into the code.

Comment: Which compiler/libc are you using?

Comment: Actually, I didn't think about that. I am using a C89 compiler included with Visual Studio 2012. I migrated to writing C programs in the IDE and was told that it does VS does not support a C99 compiler. Perhaps this is the issue. The only libraries I am using are the ANSI C ones (like stdio, stlid, time, math, etc).

Comment: Worked fine using C99 compiler. I dare not even ask what could have caused this using a C89 compiler. It could have been anything.

Comment: What is the format string you're using? Looks like some fixed decimal format that may not fit inside the fixed character restrictions.

Comment: You got this special output maybe because your compiler/libc wants to inform you that some error happened, and this specific output may depend on the specific compiler/libc you are using.

Comment: Please show us (a) the program that produce the output, and (b) the output as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, infinity is printed as `1.#INF`. A quirk in the standard library means that rounding it to three decimal places gives `1.#IO` ('F' >= '5', so it increments the 'N').

For the same reason, `-1.#IO` is negative infinity.

And yes, you could get this result by dividing by zero.

Comment: Or, another possibility is `-1.IND` for values like `0/0`.